# getting access to the exception in Django 500.html?

Tags: django, exception

How can I get access to the exception details in 500.html?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to write a middleware that overrides process_exception.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception

```
class ProcessExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        response = direct_to_template(request, "my_500_template", {'exception': exception})
        response.status_code = 500
        return response
```

Comment: it not works(( django require 500.html, though this middleware registred and access to blablabla.html

Comment: What did you try? What errors did you receive? I just tested this code with some print statements (`print 'exception is: %s' % exception`) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `django.core.handlers.base.BaseHandler`, or better one of the implementations like `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler`, and change the `handle_uncaught_exception(self, request, resolver, exc_info)` method. The last argument is the exception info as returned by `sys.exc_info`. In the case of WSGI, you would define the custom handler in your WSGI file, for instance.

Simply overwriting `handler500` in your URLconf won't work because that function does not receive any information about the actual exception.